# Laravel 5.4 storage file not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.4. I upload some document file in storage/app/public/documents folder like

```
$request->paper_file->store('documents');
```

and my file uploaded successfully.

in file system default storage is public
and public conf is like

```
'public' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
'visibility' => 'public',],
```

but when i hit /storage/documents/hQqlgifnVVH8bmrRPVdZ9aFGbhLmcc7g7bHZSX4u.pdf
it says not found 404. How to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you see the file in the filesystem? The docs show it being used like `$request->file('paper')->store('documents')` but I'm not sure what your `paper_file` bit is.

Comment: my file uploaded successfully. the file name is paper_file.

Comment: Where is `hQqlgifnVVH8bmrRPVdZ9aFGbhLmcc7g7bHZSX4u` coming from, then?

Comment: This is laravel generated dynamic file name. https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/12

Comment: could u please add your method that handles the upload process

Answer (score 46, accepted):

By default Laravel puts files in the `storage/app/public` directory, which is not accessible from the outside web. So you have to create a symbolic link between that directory and your public one:

`storage/app/public -> public/storage`

You can do that by executing the `php artisan storage:link` command ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)).

Comment: When executing this command, I had error like `The "public/storage" directory already exists.` I just deleted the empty storage folder in public before reexecuting the command

Comment: Note: If web root points to project-folder/public (recommended), then all assets & storage files are directly accessible on root of your domain, `domain.com/js/jquery.js` & `domain.com/storage/avatar.jpg` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

This problem happen to me after moving project to different folder.
If you already have storage link generated, try to **delete** public/storage folder and run again:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: delete public/storage was the key

Answer (score 5):

When you upload an image with Laravel's storage function it is stored in a storage folder.
For example:
storage/app/public/avatars/file1.png

But when you want to access it via URL, you should access it like this:

storage/avatars/file1.png

It worked for me, using Laravel 7.x.

Comment: why does this work, especially in production

Answer (score 4):

In laravel ^5.8:

- Make sure you run the command `php artisan storage:link` to link `storage/app/public` with `public/storage`.

now:

```
// this return some like 'public/documents/file.ext'
$path = $request->paper_file->store('public/documents');

// this return some like 'storage/documents/file.ext'
$publicPath = \Storage::url( $path) );

// this return some like '< APP_URL env variable >/storage/documents/file.ext'
$url = asset( $publicPath );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are coming from laravel 8.x and have indeed ran the command `php artisan storage:link`(to create a symbolic link ), but your code is not working i.e the file you are trying to load is not displaying, then you are like me.

Just like what [awais ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65849516/14669082) mentioned, His solution proved helpful with my laravel 8x project. I have not added the "storage" path name from my blade file with the asset helper function so my image path was not outputing anything but when I typed the `'storage'` path name like so `asset('storage/uploads/pic1.png)`  my code worked!

Guess this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

After running `php artisan storage:link` it creates a symbolic link in the public folder and you can retrieve record like so  `<img src='{{ asset("public/$advert6") }}' class="img-responsive">`. You should include the `public` directory