# Fail to load an image from storage on laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Can you please give me an example: I used seeder to create an image for the user, but I couldn't load it, even though I ran php artisan storage:link , and checked the path of the image (the url is correct. ). Please help me explain

The code I used in factory file to create an Image

```
    'image' => $this->faker->image('storage/app/public/users', 140, 180, null, false),
```

The img tag I used to load an image :

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/users/' . $user->image) }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3 border-radius-lg" alt="user1">
```

[When I inspected the url of an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc44z.png)

[This is my folder structer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g73BQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's your laravel project diectory bring about this problem.

Asset helper extract your image、js from laravel default public folder.

Copy a image to default public folder and try it again :)

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I fixed successfully with this link, thank you very much
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561700/laravel-5-4-storage-file-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the *storage:link* artisan command?

`php artisan storage:link`

After that you could use your img tag

```php
<img src="{{ asset('storage/users/' . $user->image) }}" class="avatar avatar-sm me-3 border-radius-lg" alt="user1">
```

Comment: It's still not working for me :3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561700/laravel-5-4-storage-file-not-found

Comment: I fixed successfully with this link, thank you very much